# UIPageViewController unresponsive in landscape orientation with UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

So here's the problem - I have `UIPageViewController` set up to support all orientations, it works as it should, showing pages and all, but gesture based page-flipping (pulling the page by its edge or corner to flip) is not working half of the time in landscape mode.

I have spine location set to `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin` for all orientations, I know I wouldn't have that problem with `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid` for landscape, but for design reasons I cannot do that.

Any suggestions? Maybe, resize the portions of the view that contain UIPageViewController's gesture recognizers? Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Sounds like an Apple bug, I'd try the latest available XCode beta and if still reproduceable, post it in bugreporter.apple.com .

Comment: how did you solved this problem ?